# What is the best way to combine two arrays using javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm going to write a function that creates an array like this

```
["0-AA", "0-BB", "1-AA", "1-BB", "2-AA", "2-BB", "3-AA", "3-BB"]
```

This function, to be exact, is a combination of the following two arrays with a separator '-'.
ex:

```
arr1 = [0,1,2,3]    //number
arr2 = ["AA", "BB"]  //produce code
```

The result is always equal to the product of the length of the two arrays
The size of both arrays is subject to change
The first array is always an integer

I want to know a good way to combine the arrays according to the rules. Is it possible to write with an array-only function such as map, concat, etc. without repetitive statements such as for statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called [Carthesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), and requires one loop per array. Here, I use `map` and `flatMap` for this purpose.

```js
function product(a, b, sep) {
  return a.flatMap(ae => b.map(be => ae + sep + be))
}

const arr1 = [0,1,2,3]
const arr2 = ["AA", "BB"]
const result = product(arr1, arr2, "-")
console.log(result)
```

Or, a generalised version, where `product` takes any number of arrays and returns the tuples, and you can join them yourself. The extra loop, provided by `reduce`, iterates over the input arrays.

```js
function product(...arrs) {
  return arrs.reduce(
    (result, arr) =>
      result.flatMap(re =>
        arr.map(ae => re.concat([ae]))
      ),
    [[]],
  )
}

const arr1 = [0,1,2,3]
const arr2 = ["AA", "BB"]
const result = product(arr1, arr2).map(items => items.join('-'))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Even better, as suggestion to you and OP, why not have the function be a pipe like map, reduce, etc that you can pass a callback function into so it works as a complete permute. Like ``product(arr1, arr2, (mem1, mem2) => `${mem1}-${mem2}`)``

Comment: @DavidTejuosho You don't have to overengineer things by passing callback to make things customizable, also there's no reason to do that if this is not reusable, even if it's reusable, we need to see if it's really necessary. Because it's also harder for others to understand the purpose of the callback. just keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce` and `.forEach`

```js
arr1 = [....]
arr2 = [....]

result = arr1.reduce((acc,value) => {
  arr2.forEach(str => acc.push(`${value}-${str}`))
  return acc;
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

While you certainly can do it the way others have shown

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3]
const array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

const product = array1
    .reduce((product, value1) => (
        product.push(array2.map(value2 => value1 + '-' + value2)),
        product), [])
    .flat()
```

I'd suggest using a more traditional function with for loops as there is a slight performance gain in speed and memory usage.

```js
function product(array1, array2, separator = '') {
    const product = []
    for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; ++i)
        for (let j = 0; j < array2.length; ++j)
            product.push(array1[i] + separator + array2[j])
    return product
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For your last requirement,

> Is it possible to write with an array-only function such as map, concat, etc. without repetitive statements such as for statements?

I assume you accept `array.forEach()`.

```js
const arr1 = [0,1,2,3];
const arr2 = ["AA", "BB"]

const result = []

arr1.forEach((number)=>{
  arr2.forEach((code)=>{
    result.push(`${number}-${code}`)
  })
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Why use forEach and an external list when you can use map?

Comment: ``let sum; 
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) sum = num1 + num2`` This code works. Does that mean it's good code?